# Mixing Java with Html or Html with Java

Tags: java, html, browser

I want to know how to mix the 2 languages together to make 1. What I mean is:

Assume you have a java program that finds the sum of 2 numbers:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  int results = findAvg(10,20);

 public int findAvg(int x, int y){
    return (x+y)/2;
 } 
}
```

Assume you have another html program below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Average of 2 numbers x and y:</h1>
<p>Ans: results</p> //where x, y and results are from the java program above
```

My question is: If I want to create a program that runs and displays the result in a browser, how will I go about it. Also, will the file be a .java or .html file. Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: Look at JSP. Netbeans with Glassfish is the easiest way to get started.

Comment: I think the words you are looking for are `servlet` and `JSP` ...

Comment: The sad thing is, that I went to look for some super-easy HelloWorld example to show him ... and bumped into this "simplest Spring tutorial": http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/ . I am crying inside.

Comment: So write one if you think it should be easier.    Please show us your better framework.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers know HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

If you want Java to perform a calculation for you, you'll need an HTTP listener (servlet) to accept an HTTP request, bind the data, perform the calculation, and send it back to the client so it can be displayed as HTML.

There are lots of solutions for sending HTML back to clients.  They fall under the category of templating.  Java Servlet Pages JSPs, Velocity, Thymeleaf, are all examples.

You can also have your client make an AJAX request to get JSON back and parse that into your HTML document.

Comment: This might be too detailed an answer.

Comment: That might be true if answers are only intended for the OP.  I think lots of people read them, so it's aimed at them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want code to run in an html page than you want javascript, not java. You can use java to write code that will be run on a server that will output custom html as responses to requests from a web browser. The best place to start learning about that is by learning about servlets.

Comment: The OP asked about Java, and programming Java applets for web pages is possible.

Comment: Nobody should be writing applets anymore.  It's not 1995.

Answer (score 0):

To be technically correct, its not mixing java and html, its about taking the control to JAVA layer by passing the parameters and then getting the processed value back in your html layer.

MVC pattern is a simple and elegant way to start with. Look for MVC hello world using JAVA examples on the net.